# Create an annotated git-tag with a particular tagger-name, tagged-date

Tags: git, git-tag

How to create an `annotated` `git-tag` with a particular `tagger-name`, `tagged-date`?

The [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) how to make it right have no such info.

From another stackoverflow question:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
git tag <tag-name> [commit]
git push origin <tag-name>
```

I have to redefine global config settings - well this is clearly not a good way

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_backdating_tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple and `CORRECT` solution would be:

```
$ git mktag <tag-file >output
```

**tag-file:**

```
object <HASH>  # hash of the commit we are want to set tag to
type commit
tag <NAME>  # name of the tag
tagger Bob Dylan <bob.dylan@boby.com> 1484015966 +0000

Message
```

**output:**

```
<HASH>  # hash of the created tag
```

**after:**

```
$ git update-ref refs/tags/<NAME of the created tag> <the HASH from output file>
```

Answer (score 3):

An annotated tag is very similar to a commit, and thus methods for `git commit` works for `git tag -a`.

- For specifying date, use `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` environment variables.
- For temporarily (for this single command only) changing git config, use `git -c config_key=config.value`

So the command you can do is:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" \
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" \
  git -c user.name='Jeff Atwood' \
      -c user.email=atwood@stackoverflow.com \
      tag -a 1234abc
```